# Which will require more force? small or big scissors?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Which will require more force (kgf)? small or big scissors?

Comment: scissors are basic class 1 levers

Comment: I think the smaller one requires a greater force as it produces a lesser torque compared to the bigger one for the same applied force while cutting.